# How to test command-line utilities for performance?

Tags: coreutils, testing

This question is somewhat related to [another one](https://askubuntu.com/a/862839/295286) on AskUbuntu, where OP asked how to decide which command to use , `sed` or `tail`. So far, all the answers have focused on using either looping in bash or `time` for single-shot runs. What bothers me about looping approach is that it introduces `bash`'s looping performance as overhead.

Are there ways to test commmand line utilities for performance without introducing shell's performance into the picture ? Are there ways other than `time` to test performance ? In general, what else can be used to test command-line utilities ?

Comment: Unroll the loop: make each iteration of the shell loop contain 100 explicitly coded iterations of the command. Whatever performance penalty the shell loop introduces will vanish into irrelevance. (Not to say that if the shell looping performance is important then your command is already plenty fast enough.)

Comment: seems kind of broad.

Answer (score 1):

`strace -c` is certainly worth a look.  [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)
:

> Count time, calls, and errors for each system call and report a summary on program exit. On Linux, this attempts to show system time (CPU time spent running in the kernel) independent of wall clock time. If -c is used with -f or -F (below), only aggregate totals for all traced processes are kept.